# Does the author have an idea where his protagonists are?

Tags: pyramides

I have just finished reading [Romain Benassaya's *Pyramides*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50527318-pyramides). In a nutshell, the novel deals with crewmembers of a colony ship that awake from hibernation and find their vessel in an inexplicable place rather than the expected colony world. The ending is rather abrupt:

> There is no explanation as to where the colony ship has ended up. The very last section kind of handwaves that question away no matter how exactly you interpret it ("everything was just a child's imagination", or "it doesn't matter anymore because the protagonists have happily reached afterlife" are both somewhat plausible interpretations).

**Has the author given any indication (in interviews or such) whether they had a clear idea what happened to the vessel?**

I'm asking this because of two impressions from the novel:

- On the one hand, finding out about the nature of the protagonists' environment is one of the major quests in the novel. It is not just a plot device to make the characters do what they do, it is also conceded quite some time as the subject of conversations (i.e. it seemed like it was not just important *that* the protagonists were trying to find out, but also *what* they were about to find out). Especially toward the end, certain observations about the environment are repeatedly noted, making it seem like they are leading up to a reveal of some kind.
- On the other hand, the last couple of chapters feel much more "rushed" than much of the book before. Reading that part, I felt like the author had decided to cram lots of events into the final couple of chapters - as if they had noticed the book was getting too long, or as if a planned book series had been cancelled. This makes me wonder whether some originally planned revelation did not make it into the novel and the author decided to wrap up the story in the described, rather abrupt manner.

Are there any statements by the author known that indicate whether they had at least an idea of what was going on? (Or were they just throwing in somewhat random inexplicable aspects for dramatic effect, without any idea how it could all be resolved?)